# preLaunchTask not executing before ${command:pickRemoteProcess} in launch config

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a dot net core 2 project that I develop on a Windows box, push to my linux box, then remote debug via vsdbg.   Everything is working, except that the vscode window for selecting the process (via ${command:pickRemoteProcess}) pops up before the preLaunchTask starts.

My prelaunch task stops the program on my linux remote box, compiles my project, pushes it to the box, then restarts it on the linux box.

How can I delay the processId ${command:pickRemoteProcess} task until the preLaunchTask is completed?

Example task:

```
{
"label": "remotePush",
"command": "cmd",
"type": "shell",
"presentation": {
    "echo": true,
    "reveal": "always",
    "focus": true,
    "panel": "dedicated",
    "showReuseMessage": true
},
"args": [
    "/C ${workspaceFolder}/remotePublish.bat"
],
"problemMatcher": [
    "$msCompile"
]
}
```

Example launch:

```
{
    "name": "Remote Testing",
    "type": "coreclr",
    "request": "attach",
    "processId": "${command:pickRemoteProcess}",
    "preLaunchTask": "remotePush",
    "pipeTransport": {
        "pipeProgram": "C:\\plink.exe",
        "pipeArgs": ["-T", "administrator@myHost"],
        "debuggerPath": "~/vsdbg/vsdbg",

    },
    "justMyCode": false,
    "sourceFileMap": {
        "/home/administrator/sites/mySite": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this issue has already been noticed before: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/75604

Comment: Sad that Microsoft has closed this. I can't see how I'd launch a Docker-ized C++ service (along with its hierarchy of startup scripts) using something like preLaunchTask and then attach to it.